# Objective C: Method using NSMutableString returns random characters

Tags: objective-c, string, nsmutablestring

I'm just getting acquainted with Objective C, and I'm a bit stuck with strings. I'm utilizing NSMutableString here. My issue is that I'm not getting my string back, just some gibberish.

My output: **You are 28 years old, weigh 200 pounds, and are a @b´�**

Thanks for looking!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject{

int age, weight;

NSMutableString *sex;

}

-(void) print;

-(void) setWeight : (int) w;
-(int) getWeight;

-(void) setAge : (int) a;
-(int) getAge;

-(void) setSex : (NSString *) s;
-(NSMutableString *) getSex;

@end

@implementation Person

-(void) print{

printf("You are %d years old, weigh %d pounds, and am a %s", 
        age, weight, sex);
}

-(void) setWeight : (int) w {weight = w;}
-(int) getWeight {return weight;}

-(void) setAge : (int) a{age = a;}
-(int) getAge{return age;}

-(void) setSex : (NSString *) s {

sex = [ [NSMutableString alloc] initWithString : s];

}

-(NSMutableString *) getSex {return sex;}

@end

int main(){

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

Person *p = [[Person alloc]init];

[p setWeight : 200];
[p setSex : @"Male"];
[p setAge : 28];

[p print];

[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSLog instead that printf. But you need to use `%@` instead that `%s`

```
-(void) print
{    
    NSLog(@"You are %d years old, weigh %d pounds, and am a %@", 
        age, weight, sex);
}
```

Otherwise you need to use the following lines of code.

```
-(void) print
{    
    const char * c_str = [sex UTF8String];

    printf("You are %d years old, weigh %d pounds, and am a %s", 
        age, weight, c_str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man...That makes sense. I was wondering why %s wouldn't be used for this type of string, since it is in C, Java, C#, etc. I also am partial to C-style I/O, but will start using NSLog() more often.

Comment: `%s` isn't used because an instance of NSString is nothing like a C string. `%s` is the specifier for a C string; `%@` specifies an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use NSLog than printf with Objective-C.

With NSLog, you use %@ as the format specifier for an object such as an NSMutableString, NSDate, NSString etc.

Therefore it would be:

```
NSLog(@"You are %d years old, weigh %d pounds, and am a %@", 
        age, weight, sex);
```

If you really want to use printf, then you need to convert to a UTF8 string e.g.

```
printf("You are %d years old, weigh %d pounds, and am a %s", 
        age, weight, [sex UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The others are right about the format specifier `%@` being used for Cocoa objects. However, I disagree with their advice to necessarily use `NSLog()`. `NSLog()` has several disadvantages. It prefixes its output with extraneous information like the date and time, process name, and PID. It writes using the Apple System Log facility. That means its output ends up cluttering the console log (see `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`). It also means that the output goes to stderr instead of stdout. (ASL doesn't necessarily output to either of those, but it can be configured to do so. `NSLog()` happens to use stderr.)

Just because you're using stdio (`printf()` and the like) doesn't mean you can't use the Cocoa string formatting facilities. You can use `NSString` to format strings using the `%@` specifier and then stdio to write out the result:

```
printf("%s", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You are %d years old, weigh %d pounds, and are a %@", age, weight, sex] UTF8String]);
```

By the way, there's no good reason to use a mutable string for the `sex` instance variable. And you ***definitely*** don't want to make the `-getSex` method's return type `NSMutableString*`. That would allow a client to alter the state of the object behind its back. Usually, you make a string property immutable and with copy semantics, so that assigning to that property replaces the current string (rather than modifying it) with a copy of the argument.

Lastly, the convention in Cocoa is for getters to be just named after the property (or, sometimes, for boolean properties, prefixed with "is"). Don't use a "get" prefix. In Cocoa, "get" methods typically output via by-reference parameters, not the return value. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html.